# Connection timed out on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup my first ec-2 instance in AWS and keep geting "`ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out`"
I followed all the solutions but nothing seems to be working for me.
Here is my inboud rules defined in security group:
[image]

I added ICMP rule to atleast ping my ec2-instance but noting seems to be working.
Steps I have tried so far:

- Instead of "Anywhere" I added my ip to allow inbound connection,
  opened port 22 through firewall.
- Enabled ICMP from firewall.
- Disabled Firewall.

So far nothing worked. Please help as this is my first exp with AWS and already have spend hours trying to figure it out.

Update: Added ACL rule

[image]
I deleted and recreated a new instance and not it works intermittently.
[image]

Comment: the security group rule seems ok, really check if the security group is assigned  to the instance and you connect to the correct ip/host. seems stupid, but happens. as well make sure you can do ssh outbound calls (e. g. from our corporate network only https calls with socs proxy are allowed)

Comment: I turned off the firewall and the problem persists. Not sure if firewall is the issue now.

Comment: are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: no definitely not. It's my local system.

Comment: @user_dev you know we use aws daily so we assume a lot of things you did not describe (please check as well it's a linux instance with public IP in the public subnet with the VPC routing table containing the internet gateway). From your information we are unable to see where the problem could be. Maybe attach the instance details, IMHO it will be something stupid / a mistake once you get over it, you will know

Comment: @gusto2 Well I tried to access it through VM created with Virtualbox and it worked like a charm. Not sure what's wrong with windows(cygwin and putty)

Comment: well it worked just once and freezed and then back to same issue. I verified almost every configuration with no luck.

Comment: Ok, after spending almost a week trying to figure out the issue. I decided to send a mail to AWS support team and they had send my account in isolation mode. They fixed the issue and now everything work as expected. Thanks everyone! Not sure if I should delete the question as the problem was with my account. But it would have been much they showed me the right error.